# Replace specific character in specific location in a string Python3

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace

I have my data like this:

```
apiserver_client_certificate_expiration_seconds_bucket{'le'= '3.1104e+07', 'node_name'= 'pool-8zd1dm4m-toev6q0bfga1cfdb-node-saspkaac'} 0.0 
apiserver_client_certificate_expiration_seconds_bucket{'le'= '+Inf', 'node_name'= 'pool-8zd1dm4m-toev6q0bfga1cfdb-node-saspkaac'} 12522.0 
apiserver_client_certificate_expiration_seconds_sum{'node_name'= 'pool-8zd1dm4m-toev6q0bfga1cfdb-node-saspkaac'} 3946064071896.744 
apiserver_client_certificate_expiration_seconds_count{'node_name'= 'pool-8zd1dm4m-toev6q0bfga1cfdb-node-saspkaac'} 12522.0 
apiserver_storage_data_key_generation_duration_seconds_bucket{'le'= '5e-06', 'node_name'= 'pool-8zd1dm4m-toev6q0bfga1cfdb-node-saspkaac'} 0.0 
apiserver_storage_data_key_generation_duration_seconds_bucket{'le'= '1e-05', 'node_name'= 'pool-8zd1dm4m-toev6q0bfga1cfdb-node-saspkaac'} 0.0
```

As you can see the format is `metrics_name{'label1'= 'value1', 'label2'= 'value2', ....'`

I want to have my data will be formatted like this: `metrics_name{label1= 'value1', label2= 'value2', ....'`

I try to use replace():

code here:

```
data = (... #above)
result = result.replace('"', '')
```

So the result return with format:
`metrics_name{label1= value1, label2= value2, ....`

But some have more/less labels than the others. So I can't find a way to just remove the character `'` in **label** and leave it in **value**

Are there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = "metrics_name{'label1'= 'value1', 'label2'= 'value2', ..."

result = re.sub(r"'(\w+)'=", "\g<1>=", text)
print(result)
```

This gives `metrics_name{label1= 'value1', label2= 'value2', ...`.